# How to assign the correct type to reduce method and its callback function based on deeply nested object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

A component receives an accessor key, a dot-separated string with an index like `"[0].key12.key56.key99"`, and an array of JSON objects from an API call. Then, the component updates its state according to the mapping of parsed API data. For example:

Accessor key: `"[0].key1.key2.key3"`

API data: `[{key1: {key2: key3: ['a', 'b', 'c']}}, {key15: {key26: key37: ['d', 'f', 'g']}}]`

New intended component status: `[{label: 'a', value: 'a'}, {label: 'b', value: 'b'}, {label: 'c', value: 'c'}]`

It's done in the following snippet:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState<Array<{ label: string; value: string }>>();

const getter = (obj: any, i: string) => obj[i];

const accessorExpression = /^(?:\[(?<index>\d)\])?\.?(?<key>[\w.]+)$/;
const match = accessorExpression.exec(accessor);
const { index, key } = match?.groups || {};

if (index && key) {
  setData(
    key
      .split('.')
      .reduce(getter, data[index])
      .map((item: string) => ({ label: item, value: item }))
  );
}
```

It is worth noting that I can't attribute a type to the data coming from the API. The only thing that I know upfront is that the value accessed is always a string array.

The code bellow works well, but I'd like to assign the correct type to the reduce method and its callback function in order to get rid of the `any` type. How can I do that?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-vkiy35

Comment: You can use `Record<string, any>`. Or `Record<string, Record<string, any>>`. Or really `type ArbitraryNested = {[key: string]: ArbitraryNested}`. You will still need type assertions though in one place or another, and probably a union `ArbitraryNested | string[]` given your usage of the `reduce` result.

Comment: ```type ArbitraryNested = {[key: string]: ArbitraryNested | string[]}``` results in ```Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'string[]'.ts(2769)```

Comment: Yes, you'll need to cast that: `const getter = (obj: ArbitraryNested | string[], i: string) => (obj as ArbitraryNested)[i];`

Comment: Doing that cast, it results in ```This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'ArbitraryNested | string[] | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])' are callable.
    Type 'ArbitraryNested' has no call signatures.ts(2349)```

Comment: Please, take a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-vkiy35

Comment: Well the result of the `reduce` call is (must be) still `ArbitraryNested | string[]`, since with the arbitrary nesting you don't know if you really accessed a key the right number of times, so you'll need to assert the type of that as `string[]` before calling `map` on it.